# boost::unordered_map is... ordered?

Tags: c++, boost

I have a boost::unordered_map, but it appears to be in order, giving me an overwhelming feeling of "You're Doing It Wrong". Why is the output to this in order? I would've expected the underlying hashing algorithm to have randomized this order:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/unordered_map.hpp>

int main()
{
    boost::unordered_map<int, int> im;

    for(int i = 0; i < 50; ++i)
    {
        im.insert(std::make_pair(i, i));
    }

    boost::unordered_map<int, int>::const_iterator i;

    for(i = im.begin(); i != im.end(); ++i)
    {
        std::cout << i->first << ", " << i->second << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

...gives me...

```
0, 0
1, 1
2, 2
...
47, 47
48, 48
49, 49
```

---

Upon examination of boost's source code:

```
inline std::size_t hash_value(int v)
{
    return static_cast<std::size_t>(v);
}
```

...which would explain it. The answers below hold the higher level thinking, as well, which I found useful.

Comment: Instead of inserting `i`, try inserting (and printing to console at the same time while inserting) random numbers, see if the results are still ordered, or if they are simply ordered by the order they were inserted in...

Comment: If you need random order, use std::random_shuffle :)

Comment: @Drakosha: I'm not looking for random order, but an in-order unordered_map left me feeling uneasy. (The non-minimal testcase has several thousand integers, but they're still in order)

Comment: @FWFD: (lol at your handle) Inserting rand() gives me an unordered output.

Comment: @Thanatos: Just as I thought! :)

Comment: @FWFD: To clarify: It wasn't either: They were neither ordered nor in the order I inserted them.

Comment: There's an explanation of the strategy used in the docs: http://www.boost.org/doc/html/unordered/rationale.html#unordered.rationale.number_of_buckets You'll only get collisions if you're using a multiple of a factor of the number of buckets - which is unlikely since they're primes.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

While I can't speak to the boost internals as I'm not a C++ guy, I can propose a few higher-level questions that may alleviate your concerns:

1) What are the guarantees of an "unordered" map?  Say you have an ordered map, and you want to create a map that does not guarantee ordering.  An initial implementation may simply use the ordered map.  It's almost never a problem to provide *stronger* guarantees than you advertise.

2) A hash function is something that hashes X -> int.  If you already have an integer, you could use the identity function.  While it may not be the most efficient in all cases, it could explain the behavior you're seeing.

Basically, seeing behavior like this is not necessarily a problem.

Comment: I was not expecting the use of an identity function for a hash function, but it would seem that this is exactly what boost is doing. I suppose without domain knowledge of the inputs, such a hash is going to work about as well as any.

Comment: @Thanatos - since the result of the hash function is a `size_t` (at least for `boost::unordered_map`) and an `int` will always fit into a `size_t`, there's no reason to do anything but an identity function to hash an `int`.

Comment: @Michael Burr - I wasn't concerned about the semantics of the language - I'm looking at the purpose of a hash function being to prevent collisions between input, so that the hash table has a chance of being O(1). I'm used to seeing rather random hash function outputs.

Comment: @Thantos: but if the property to be hashed is smaller than or equal in size to the hash, then there's no reason to perform any transformation on the property to produce a perfect hash - regardless of language. The identify function produces a nice, simple perfect hash in those cases.

Answer (score 11):

It is probably because your hashes are small integers.
Hash tables usually calculate the number of bucket in which to put the item like this: `bucket_index = hash%p` where `p` is a prime number, which is the number of hashtable buckets, which is large enough to provide low frequency of collisions.

For integers hash equals to the value of the integer.
You have a lot of data, so hashtable selects a large p.
For any p larger than i, `bucket_index = i%p = i`.

When iterating, the hashtable returns items from its buckets in order of their indexes, which for you is the order of keys. :)

Try using larger numbers if you want to see some randomness.

Answer (score 2):

You're doing it right. unordered_map doesn't claim to have random order. In fact, it makes no claims about order whatsoever. You shouldn't *expect* anything whatsoever in terms of order, and that goes for disorder!

Answer (score -3):

This is because map by default is ordered by 'order of insertion of keys' means if you insert keys 1,2,3,4,5 and print it you will always get 1,2,3,4,5 so it looks ordered. Try to add with random key values and see the result. It will not be same every time, as it should not be.