# First unique character in string using Unordered_map c++

Tags: c++, string, unordered-map

I am trying to find the first unique character of a string using unordered_map in c++. [LeetCodeProblem](https://leetcode.com/problems/first-unique-character-in-a-string/) My code:

```
int firstUniqChar(string s) {
    unordered_map<char,int> m;
    for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++){
        m[s[i]]++;
    }
    unordered_map<char,int>::iterator mit;
    for(mit=m.begin();mit!=m.end();mit++){
        if(mit->second ==1)
            for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++){
                if(mit->first == s[i])
                    return i;
            }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

The output is not correct.
If I try to debug it in eclipse it says could not resolve unordered_map. I could not find the bug in my code. Please help me in understanding the bug.

Comment: If an answer posted below really answered your question, please accept it. Read more here: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`unordered_map` doesn't ensure that the elements are stored in the order you've inserted. So when you are iterating over it, there is no guarantee that the first element for which `second` is 1 is necessarily the first unique character.

You should iterate over the string instead:

```
int firstUniqChar(string s) {
    unordered_map<char,int> m;
    for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++){
        m[s[i]]++;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
      if (m[s[i]] == 1) {
        return i;
      }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: oh..I didn't know this. Thanks.
But what is the order in which the elements are store then?

Comment: @rowang unspecified. Depends on hash function, amount of buckets (which changes over time), how hash value is mapped to buckets, etc.

Comment: Go through [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3176621/c-is-the-unordered-map-really-unordered) to understand better.

Comment: Thanks guys. Understood.