# loop a std::unordered_map, the sequence is always the sequence I insert elements?

Tags: c++, c++11, insert, sequence, unordered-map

I constructed a std::unordered_map and use for loop to visit it.
I found that the sequence of the iteration result shows the elements is put in the sequence that I created those elements, no matter how I inserted them.

Is this part of C++ standard that unordered_map, when visited, the iteration sequence is the insertion sequence? Or this is implementation preference?

I ask this question is, I wish to know if this feature, is something I can rely in my c++ code?

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3176621/c-is-the-unordered-map-really-unordered

Comment: No, you cannot rely on this behavior in your C++ code.

Comment: In general: No! For explaining your specific observation: What did you use as keys? Please post some example code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The standard makes no guarantees about the order of elements in the unordered associative containers <sup>†</sup> (unordered map, set and their multivalued versions) and you can not rely on any particular ordering in your code.

<sup>†</sup> Except for a special case [[unord.req]/6](http://eel.is/c++draft/unord.req#6) (standard draft, emphasis mine):

> An unordered associative container supports unique keys if it may contain at most one element for each key. Otherwise, it supports equivalent keys. unordered_set and unordered_map support unique keys. unordered_multiset and unordered_multimap support equivalent keys. In containers that support equivalent keys, elements with equivalent keys are adjacent to each other in the iteration order of the container. Thus, although **the absolute order of elements in an unordered container is not specified**, its elements are grouped into equivalent-key groups such that all elements of each group have equivalent keys. Mutating operations on unordered containers shall preserve the relative order of elements within each equivalent-key group unless otherwise specified.