# why there is abnormalities in printing the key and value of un_ordered map and map(dictionary)?

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, unordered-map

here is my code please tell me why it is not printing from starting as in map it is printing in correct manner

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
unordered_map<int,int>arr;
for(int i=1;i<=10;i++){
    arr[i]=i*i;
}

for(auto it=arr.begin();it!=arr.end();it++){
    cout<<it->first<<" "<<it->second<<"\n";
}

cout<<"normal map \n";

map<int,int>arry;
for(int i=1;i<=10;i++){
    arry[i]=i*i;
}

for(auto it=arry.begin();it!=arry.end();it++){
    cout<<it->first<<" "<<it->second<<"\n";
}
```

}

and my output is

10 100

9 81

8 64

7 49

6 36

5 25

1 1

2 4

3 9

4 16

normal map

1 1

2 4

3 9

4 16

5 25

6 36

7 49

8 64

9 81

10 100

why un_ordered map printing the value in this fashion why not it printing like map

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3176621/is-the-unordered-map-really-unordered) would be helpful for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`std::unordered_map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) doesn't order keys in any specific order. This is why it is called *unordered*.

> Internally, the elements are not sorted in any particular order, but organized into buckets. Which bucket an element is placed into depends entirely on the hash of its key. This allows fast access to individual elements, since once the hash is computed, it refers to the exact bucket the element is placed into.